# count unique values for one column with groupby (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to count for each **date** the number of unique **customer_id** grouped by **device** and **country**

Main table

```
date        device   country  customer_id
2019-01-01  phone    UK       1284
2019-01-01  phone    UK       3932
2019-01-01  phone    UK       1284
2019-01-01  tablet   UK       1284
2019-01-01  tablet   UK       3822
2019-01-01  tablet   UK       3924
2019-01-01  tablet   JP       9393
2019-01-01  tablet   JP       3932
2019-01-01  tablet   JP       3932
```

Output table

```
date         device country  count_distinct_customerID
2019-01-01   phone  UK       2
2019-01-01   tablet UK       3
2019-01-01   tablet JP       2
```

This is what I've tried so far, but no success:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['date','device','country']).agg(['nunique'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `date`, `device` & `country` then use `.agg` to aggregate the number of unique `customer_id` in grouped dataframe:

```
df1 = (
    df.groupby(['date','device','country'], sort=False)
    .agg(count_distinct_customerID=('customer_id', 'nunique'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

---

```
# print(df1)
         date  device country  count_distinct_customerID
0  2019-01-01   phone      UK                          2
1  2019-01-01  tablet      UK                          3
2  2019-01-01  tablet      JP                          2
```